# Transclude and ng-bind: how to render sub-directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently I'm having a problem to understand how to change dynamically the content of a directive in AngularJS.

At first, in my HTML, I have a parent directive containing a child directive. From time to time, I would like to refresh the content of parent directive, but the child directive I'm trying to inject is not initialized by AngularJS. I did a JSFiddle to explain my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/koj2e1th/2/

When I update the content using $timeout, the directive is not initialized:

```
$timeout(function(){
    html = '<child-dir>TIMEOUT</child-dir>'
    scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
}, 2500)
```

I tried using $compile (saw this on other questions) but I did not manage to make it work properly. Could you explain me how to make $compile work in this context, and to have my `child-dir` rendered properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child-dir directive is not compiled. before the directive is added to the DOM it should be compiled with a scope. [click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('parentDir', function($sce, $timeout, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
            transcludeFn(function(html) {
              $timeout(function() {
                html = _.reduce(html, function(carry, domElement) {
                  if (domElement.outerHTML) {
                      return carry + domElement.outerHTML
                  } else {
                    return carry;
                  }
                }, '')
                scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
              })
            })
            var el = $compile( "<child-dir>TIMEOUT</child-dir>" )(scope );
            element.parent().append( el );
        }
    }});

demo.directive('childDir', function($sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div>CHILD DIR</div>'
    }});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my problem. I was trying to use both $sce and $compile, but thanks to your example I noticed I was wrong to use $sce here.

Answer (score 1):

From the snippet you've provided, it seems that you are trying to handle transclusion yourself.

Well actually you don't need to do so as far as the `tranclude` property and the `ng-transclude` attributes are at your disposal.

You can refine your directive definitions to accommodate the feature as in the following:

```
/* ... */
.directive('parentDir', function(){
   return {
     transclude: true,
     link: function(){ /* Any DOM manipulation logic if required */ },
     template: '<div ><h2>Parent Directive</h2><div ng-transcude></div></div>'
   };
})
.directive('childDir', function(){
   return {
     transclude: true,
     template: '<div ><h4>Child directive</h4><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
   };
});
```

**Note** the usage of `ng-transclude` attribute in the template. This tells AngularJS as to *where exactly* the transcluded elements/directives are to be put.

So if you had your directives in the following format:

```
<parent-dir>
   <child-dir></child-dir>
</parent-dir>
```

the `<child-dir>` would be placed in the `<div ng-transclude>` part of `<parent-dir>` template in the final *compiled* version.

### [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/bbg644j5/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did not know this worked that way. I had to keep the transclusion function because in my project I need to apply modifications to the transcluded content, but I'll keep that in mind for my next directives!